# Migrating SQL Server Apply query to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

What shall be the equivalent of below Sql Server query in Oracle:

```
select dd.dname, e.ename
from emp e
outer apply 
(select top 1 dname from dept d where d.did=e.did order by bdate) dd
```

Please note that the actual query is very different but the concept is same. Please pardon me for any syntax error in above query.

I tried below Oracle query:

```
select dd.dname, e.ename
from emp e
left join 
(select * from 
(select dname from dept d where d.did=e.did order by bdate)
where rownum=1) dd
```

But, it is giving below error:

```
Error at Command Line:6 Column:18
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `LATERAL JOIN` in Oracle, which is equivalent for `CROSS APPLY` in SQL Server.

Comment: In Oracle, lateral is automatic. So, I tried cross join and get "%s: invalid identifier" error at e.did in above Oracle query

Comment: I found that lateral join is added in Oracle 12c version. However, I am using Oracle 11g version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arrange rows at first and then take first rows:

```
select e.ename, d.dname
  from emp e
  left join  (
      select dept.dname, dept.did, row_number()
         over (partition by did order by bdate) rn from dept) d
    on e.did = d.did and d.rn=1
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e74fd/1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

On clause was missing after join. So, I convert the query into group by query and it works:

```
select dd.dname, e.ename
from emp e
left join 
(select min(bdate), dname, did from dept d group by dname, did)dd
on dd.did=e.did
```

Comment: there is one problem with the above solution. It gives invalid identifier error on adding, "where d.did=e.did" in the group by query. It shall be solved by lateral join. But, lateral join is added in Oracle 12c version. However, I am using Oracle 11g version.